# @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL Not working

Tags: java, json, serialization

I'm creating a DTO that looks like this:

```
uses com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
uses com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude
uses gw.integration.document.production.json.JSONSerializable 

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
class AccountDataForAPI extends JSONSerializable {

    @JsonProperty(:value = "Account5")
    var account5: Boolean as account5

    @JsonProperty(:value = "SalesAmountOver5k")
    var salesAmountOver5k: Integer as SalesAmountOver5k= 0

    @JsonProperty(:value = "SalesAmountOver10k")
    var salesAmountOver10k: Integer as SalesAmountOver10k= 0
    
    @JsonProperty(:value = "inventory_amount")
    var inventoryAmount: Integer

    @JsonProperty(:value = "year")
    var year: Integer

    @JsonProperty(:value = "num_losses")
    var numLosses: Integer


    construct () {}

    construct(priorAccount: priorAccount) {
        this.account5= null
        this.salesAmountOver5k= null
        this.salesAmountOver10k= null
        this.inventoryAmount= priorAccount?.InventoryAmount
        this.year= priorAccount?.priorAccount?.Year
        this.numLosses= priorAccount?.NumLosses
    }

    function setPropertyByCodeIdentifier(question: Question) {
        var typeInfo: ItypeInfo = this.IntrinsicType.getTypeInfo()
        var prop : IPropertyInfo = typeInfo.getProperty(question.Question.CodeIdentifier)
        var answerUnformatted = question.AnswerUnformatted

        if(prop != null and prop.isWritable()) {
            switch(prop.FeatureType.Name) {
                case "java.lang.Integer":
                  prop.getAccessor().setValue(this, answerUnformatted.IntegerAnswer)
                  break
                case "java.lang.Boolean":
                    prop.getAccessor().setValue(this, answerUnformatted.BooleanAnswer)
                    break
                default:
                    prop.getAccessor().setValue(this, answerUnformatted.TextAnswer)
                    break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically this DTO will be instantiated with either an empty constructor, or the priorAccount constructor.

Depending on which constructor is initialized, we will create a JSON request object with only some of the fields. The rest of the fields that are null should NOT be returned.

I followed the documentation - and it is returning a JSON object with some of the properties that have null values still.

Why is `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` not working?

Comment: It doesn't look like a Java syntax, so my guess that the fields are actually wrapped into some other object. What are the actual _Java_ types for the fields?

Comment: Sorry this is written in Gosu, which is built over Java

Comment: I understand that. My question is about the `Java type`, what Gosu uses for the final type when it compiles it to the bytecode? If it's some kind of a wrapper, that would be a reason.